# Display one post randomly from category on home page

Tags: posts, query, customization

I have a custom post type called "Milo-Books" and a category named "Featured" with ID of "100".

I want to run a query which pulls out on post from this category on the homepage, but randomly and I can't seem to get it to work. Could anybody help me out.

```
<?php
        $args = array( 
        'post_type'         => 'milo-books', 
        'cat'               => 100,
        'show_posts'        => 1,
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'orderby'           => 'RAND'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2>Featured Title</h2>

<div class="featured-content-container">        

</div><!--End Featured Content Container-->
```

It only displays one of my posts. In my custom post type I have set 3 posts up with the category FEATURED.

Have I missed something? Because If I change the posts_per_page to 3 it displays all three so they are recognised in that category. Just can't get them to display randomly.

Cheers

Dan

Comment: Is the show_posts standing there for something? Never seen it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer it seems was using 'RAND' instead of 'rand'.